# Node.js socket.io and Opera

Tags: node.js, socket.io, opera

when trying connect to server from opera, i'm got this server log:

```
 debug - client authorized
 info  - handshake authorized bIDigTGEsQIc1GBXIjHk
 debug - client authorized
 info  - handshake authorized AtLXuLjQ9XkzgXZrIjHl
 debug - client authorized
 info  - handshake authorized SsW2FTj3khC-1PDXIjHm
```

All another browser — mozilla, IE, chrome works perfectly.

Version Node.js - v0.11.2-pre, socket.io server - 0.9.14, socket.io client - 0.9.11

Answer (score 0):

Opera version 12.1 supports websockets. Opera 11.0 - 12.0 only supports it partially. Before 11.0 it did not support websockets.

Upgrade your Opera to 12.1 to use websockets.

Comment: Oh, ye, forget specify Opera version. I have last version — 12.15.